# Bash alias to start/stop multiple service

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, lamp

I am a developer working with LAMP stack.

My pc run arch linux so it is systemd based.

it has a limited amount of ram 8Gb:

- sometime I use it for work
- sometime for play games

I want to easily be able start/stop the LAMP services with one command.
So I can keep them disabled to save some ram.

How can I accomplish the above without writing every time:

```
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
sudo systemctl start mariadb.service
sudo systemctl start redis.service
```

I'll post below my solution in case some newbie bash lover need it, if you have a better solution please add it and I'll upvote it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**First disable the services** so they don't start at the boot:

```
sudo systemctl disable httpd.service
sudo systemctl disable mariadb.service
sudo systemctl disable redis.service
```

**Then Edit `.bashrc`** in your home and add to the end

```
web() {
    #do things with parameters like $1 such as
    sudo systemctl "$1" httpd.service
    sudo systemctl "$1" mariadb.service
    sudo systemctl "$1" redis.service
}
```

Now you can start/stop/restart all the related service with a simple

```
web start
```

Change web() with whatever you please.

Comment: This is a function, not an alias.  That is actually a good thing; you should probably avoid aliases altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the note, why aliases are bad ?

Comment: E.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233751/19240 shows a few problems with them.

Comment: @Francesco, Aliases can't take arguments while functions can. That's why we should use functions and avoid aliases altogether.

Answer (score 0):

you can define and set an alias for start and one for stop
like below command:

```
alias start_services='systemctl start httpd.service mariadb.service redis.service'
alias stop_services='systemctl stop httpd.service mariadb.service redis.service'
```